# in drupal's theme_form_element function, array += operator throws Unsupported operand error

Tags: php, arrays, drupal-7, operator-overloading

In drupal, an uncatchable php error is thrown by this code:

```
/*
* @param $variables
*   An associative array containing:
*   - element: An associative array containing the properties of the element.
*     Properties used: #title, #title_display, #description, #id, #required,
*     #children, #type, #name.
*
* @ingroup themeable
*/
function theme_form_element($variables) {
  //print_r($variables); die("daa`");
  $element = &$variables['element'];
  // This is also used in the installer, pre-database setup.
  $t = get_t();

  // This function is invoked as theme wrapper, but the rendered form element
  // may not necessarily have been processed by form_builder().

  $element += array(
    '#title_display' => 'before',
  );
...
```

The last line of drupal's function throws the error.

`$variables['element']` is an array when it enters the function.  When the `$element` reference is assigned to it, it changes (within `$variables`) from type `Array` to type `&Array`.  The variable `$element` reports itself as type `Array`.

The following lines no not throw the same error when used instead of the += operator:

```
$element = $element + array();
$new = array_merge($element, array());
```

@iputonmyrobeandwizardhat asked for an sscce, which I attempted to provide below.  However, the code does not cause the same error in isolation that it throws while in use in drupal's rendering process.  Can anyone recommend a method to isolate the error?

```
<?php
function theme_form_element($variables) { 
  $element = &$variables['element'];         
  var_dump($variables);                //['element'] becomes type &array

  //not fatal
  $element2 = $element + array( '#title' => 'before'); 

  //not fatal
  $element3 = array_merge($element, array( '#title' => 'before'));   

  $element += array( '#title_display' => 'before');  
    var_dump($element);
}

$variables_array = array
(
'element' => array
    (
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'First Name:',
        '#default_value' => '',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 64,
        '#description' => 'First name',
        '#required' => 1,
        '#input' => 1,
        '#autocomplete_path' => '',
        '#process' => Array ('ajax_process_form'),

        '#theme' => 'textfield',
        '#theme_wrappers' => Array('form_element'),

        '#defaults_loaded' => 1,
        '#tree' => '',
        '#parents' => Array('first_name'),

        '#array_parents' => Array('first_name'),

        '#weight' => 0,
        '#processed' => 1,
        '#attributes' => Array(),

        '#title_display' => 'before',
        '#id' => 'edit-first-name',
        '#name' => 'first_name',
        '#value' => '',
        '#ajax_processed' => '',
        '#sorted' => 1,
        '#children' => '<input type="text" id="edit-first-name" name="first_name" value="" size="60" maxlength="64" class="form-text required" />'
    )

);    
?>
```

The input:

```
// base64_encode(serialize($variables));
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
```

Comment: post an [sscce](http://sscce.org/). don't waste our time assuming what crazy values your variables might have.

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat They have some values.  But they also have very specific types.  I think i can fulfill your request, though.

Comment: You didnt bother running your code did you?

Comment: I did write it too quickly in the editor, you are correct.  And it doesn't throw the error, which you must have noticed.  I'll move the discussion to your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+= works fine with arrays and references.

```
$arr = array(1);
$e = &$arr;
$e += array(1,2);

print_r($e);//Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )
```

http://codepad.org/0M5ChPgt

Comment: so the answer is: `$variables['element']` is not an array.

Comment: I expanded my example to use the same input that causes the error within drupal, but my example still does not produce the same result.  Can you recommend further improvements to try to isolate the error?

Comment: Your problem is you aren't paying close attention to your code. You've had a misspelled variable in your sscce since the beginning and you still haven't noticed it despite the fact that var_dump() has been telling you that it's null. If you aren't using var_dump() to inspect the values of your variables and let the results guide your investigations, then you're not really doing any debugging - you're just making random, unguided code changes and hoping something will work eventually, and you're goiong to be at it for a very long time...

Comment: I did notice the error on my computer's file, where I fixed it.  I apologize for not fixing it in my posted example.  I have since done so.
I am aware that the problem does not exist in my posted code, can you offer any assistance in improving the example?  The sscce link does not cover that topic of errors within large code bases.

Comment: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4   I also editted the question, since it clearly is not a php bug.

Comment: if there's no sensitive info in it, base64_encode(serialize()) the runtime value that causes the problem and post it here for inspection.

Comment: Too long for comments, it's added to the end of the question.

Comment: I don't have any new idea aside from maybe the function is called more than once, and you're intercepting the wrong values/call.

Comment: I think I've eliminated that possibility.  I can see that `['element']` index and the reference, and I can dump them both out without die statements, and subsequently reach the error line.  The other site pages will function while the die statements are present, so I don't think the function is used anywhere else, although that could use more thorough testing.  I'll be sure to post back if I solve it, since you are now hopelessly invested in my bad question. :)

Comment: @iputonmyrobeanwizardhat Nope.  I ended up abandoning my effort to build a drupal custom form element renderer, which was what lead me into this trouble.

Anyway, thanks for asking and for the initial effort to answer.  You and @ dev-null-dweller wrote things that must be true, but the problem is surely me misusing drupal somehow.  Whatever I'm doing wrong, I can't nail it down.  I logged in to to delete this question; it won't be helpful to anyone.